# Can you hide your face from a facehugger?

Tags: alien-franchise

I think I found a flaw to the alien franchise. As the other day I was wondering if you can just cover your face against a wall or your arms? I mean if you've been cocooned then you can't move your head so your doomed there but if you just hide your face the facehugger can't get you.

Comment: They're really quite strong.

Comment: Yes but the facehugger just can turn you around to face them Right?!?

Comment: Yes. They seem to be more than sufficiently strong to prevent someone from flinging them off.

Comment: I know that you can't fling them off because they have the strength to tear your face off but if you saw a egg hatching then you turn around to face the wall it's not like they can turn you around to face them

Comment: Obviously this isn’t the core of your question, but how is this a flaw as regards the franchise? There aren’t a lot of occasions when characters get impregnated by facehuggers, and when it does happen, it’s usually by surprise.

Comment: Turn your face to the wall and the other Aliens will just *love* that. Easy meat!

Comment: @Paulie_D there's more than 1 way into the human body...

Comment: You are, of course, assuming that [they only go for the face](http://www.sluggy.com/comics/archives/daily/971012).

Comment: It's not really a hug, you know.

Comment: You could likely buy a suit of mitrhil plate armour from your neighbourhood dwarven smithy. Make sure the helmet has no possible way that the face hugger can get at your face. If all else fails wear a fish bowl with acid-proof, unbreakable glass on your head.

Comment: I misread the question and thought you meant that if the facehugger couldn't see your face (whatever they use for locating it, as aliens don't seem to have eyes), maybe you wouldn't trigger the implantation instinct.

Comment: I'm gonna guess the facehugger will just go "meh," and figure you for one of those weirdos who also like holes in their arms.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder They aim for the face through a space suit helmet from inside of an egg well enough.

Answer (score 78):

"Turning to face a wall" isn't going to do jack squiddly against a facehugger. They're literally built to hug your face and plant eggs in your chest, and nothing you can do as a lone human is going to prevent that once they've jumped at you.

Their little ovipositor (Egg Injector) secretes a kind of acidic substance that allows them to pierce pretty much any material. It got through Kane's helmet, after all. So if they wanted, they could probably just make a new hole at the back of your head after you've turned around.

Best defence against a facehugger if you're by yourself is to have a shotgun or a flamethrower in your hands and blast every last one that thinks you're a good place to start a hatchery.

Comment: I really like this answer. _jack squiddly_ + _ovipositor_ = +1 from me!

Comment: Nice first post.

Comment: Haha, thanks. And a +1 from you gets you a +1 from me ;)

Comment: Surely they would not kill the intended incubator though, that would after all defeat the purpose of finding a nice warm acidic place to lay eggs

Comment: Actually, that is something I've wondered about them. Do they necessarily need LIVE humans in order to hatch Aliens?

From what I can tell, the incubation period for Facehugger eggs is quite short. In AVP, somebody gets hugged & choked out, knocking them out. They awake minutes before the alien explodes out of them, suggesting incubation of a few hours at most. A human chest cavity (where the eggs are laid) can stay warm for up to 3 hours after death. So it might be theoretically possible for one of their eggs to hatch out of a human, even if that human dies as a result of the egg-laying.

Comment: I'm sure they would avoid killing the host at all costs if they could avoid it, but if the host somehow blocked all other access to their face, then maybe the Facehugger would sort of burrow into them, lay the eggs anyway and, assuming the host doesn't die immediately, have a place warm enough, long enough, for the eggs to hatch.

Comment: Actually the best defense is to take off and nuke the site from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.

Comment: @ChrisMorris If you want to make an omelette you gotta break a few eggs.

Answer (score 46):

It's hard to say for sure, but in [Aliens](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090605/) at least, it takes the combined effort of 4 adults (3 of which are marines, 1 of which is [Vasquez](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYkxCzBszOQ). Although arguably, Ripley might not be giving it her all), to pry a facehugger off Ripley.

[image]

We'd have to assume they are very strong creatures and so facing a wall or covering your face with your arms probably wouldn't be adequate protection.

And like Mikey Mouse points out in the comment below, their first job is really to choke you unconscious. After you pass out, it doesn't really matter what direction your facing.

Comment: As seen in this picture, step one for the hugger isn't to hug, it's to whip that tail around the victims neck. Covering your face or turning to a wall won't be much use when it chokes you unconcious like it did to Kane in Alien.

Comment: You know, this never really made sense. Obviously they're strong and determined, but there's still this thing called physics--a creature of that size just can't weigh that much. It'd have to have some source of leverage to need 4 people to pick it up.

Comment: @Tiercelet crazy strong tail?

Comment: @Tiercelet It's not about weight, it's about the force it can exert.  A bull terrier is about the same size, but no animal handler in their right mind would try picking up a pissed-off pitbull.

Comment: @Graham That is because of teeth first of all, and the risk of dropping it.  Not because it is hard to move them around.

Comment: @Yakk You've clearly never tried picking up a struggling animal, with or without its teeth in play.  The problem isn't lifting that mass of animal, it's lifting that mass of *resisting* animal.  Add claws, and it becomes painful.  And constrictor snakes demonstrate clearly how locking a flexible body around their targe is a successful strategy for taking down creatures much larger than them.  If you imagine a facehugger as a pitbull, minus teeth, plus boa constrictor, then you're in the ballpark.  And that's not a healthy ballpark for humans to go one-on-one with.

Comment: A freaking _cat_ is pretty darn hard to restraint when it's freaking out.

Comment: 0/10 - would not attempt to rescue a robin caught in some string, again.

Answer (score 27):

That's like saying that I can't punch you in the face if you're looking the other way. Technically true, but unlikely to be of any practical help.

However, to answer the original question, in the [Aliens: Berserker](http://alienanthology.wikia.com/wiki/Aliens:_Berserker_(comic)) comic, a team of alien removal specialists use special anti-facehugger masks, which allows someone to get taken alive for impregnation, and thus reveal the location of the hive.

[image: Aliens: Berserker #1 - Page 15]

Comment: Well, if this is canon, then it seems there IS a kind of "Hide your face" defence against a facehugger. I wonder what those masks are made of?

Nice answer.

Comment: Either unobtanium or plotonium of course ;-) What else would you make such a mask off of?

Comment: [This](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Plotonium) plotonium, @JohnKeates?

Comment: @JanDvorak sounds about right

Comment: +1 for the first sentence. It's technically correct which is the best kind of correct.

Answer (score 12):

Facehuggers have a variety of ways of giving you a face full of alien wing-wong.

As we see in most movies, the prefer to attack by surprise, are extremely fast and are capable of very long jumps, leaving you with no time to turn away.

They also seem to strike the neck of their victim (as seen in *Aliens* and *AVP*), throttling them into near unconsciousness before settling onto the face of their victim.

As we see in *Alien* they are also capable of secreting acid capable of melting through a very thick looking space helmet, so covering your face with your arms might not be a good idea.

In some of the expanded universe material, such as *Earth War*, one character remarks that he's even seen facehuggers take down adult lions.

Comment: Where did a facehugger encounter a lion?

Comment: @Malvolio if I remember in a lab. Weyland-Yutani experiments

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't work. Their design (strength, agility and process) is to subdue first on contact and use as an incubator when successful. Short of killing them, what would work is figuring out how they aim, and either give them a false target (a clay head? ballistic gel? mirror? hologram?) or be somewhere they can't get to. (so, be an unreachable/invisible target)

For example, live on a planet while they are stuck in a star's gravitational pull. They won't get near you.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange. Could you elaborate on *why* it would not work?

Comment: Added the 'why' :)

Comment: Sure... launching them to a low heliocentric orbit seems like the best way to rid of these critters.

Answer (score 0):

Bishop said in Aliens, that as soon as the alien had planted the embryo, the blood of the facehugger quickly oxidizes and the creature dies.  Since many types of glass won't melt with acid, and seeing that it's very difficult to remove one of those organisms, once attached, why not use a syringe with a glass needle (glass that is tempered to their acidity) and inject an oxidizing agent? Even a strong base to neutralize the acid blood and thereby killing the creature before it finishes the gestation period. Then you pull it off and see if you can extract the embryo before it matures. I also wonder what localized liquid nitrogen would do to their tissue?

Comment: But that would require another person to help you - the OP asks if you can sue your hands to shield yourself, removing the need for another person.

Comment: well in that case I'd say a person by themselves should just run.  If your face is covered, the creature will still put the victim in a coma by using it's tail to reduce oxygen to the brain.  then the victim can't use their arms or cover their face.  If you're locked in a cell with an egg, then its gameover lol!

Comment: @Gallifreyan _sue_ your _hands_? Talk about frivolous litigation!

Comment: @SQB Not that frivolous. Tell me why hand cuffs are hand cuffs and not people cuffs? Because hands are almost always the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how about using an ape suit? They're canon:

http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Apesuit

> The Apesuit is a specialized armored suit, used by both the United States Colonial Marine Corps and Weyland-Yutani combat personnel. The suit effectively protects the wearer from the hazardous effects of Xenomorph acidic blood.
>
> [...] it additionally protects the wearer from Facehugger attacks as long as they are not comatose, as the Facehugger will then have time to pry the suit's mask off and gain access to the victim within. The Apesuits in this game are considerably bulkier than those seen previously.

Comment: AvP is "canon" in the same way that the video games are :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could, but the tail would choke you out until you lost consciousness, and then the fingers, which are apparently very strong, would clamp onto your head and not let go. That nasty tube would be down your throat before you knew it.

Comment: This doesn't offer anything that isn't already in the (better sourced) answers above.